# Wireless communication between a RPI and a Android app - without internet

Tags: wifi, pi-4, wireless, android, node.js

I got a RPI4 and I would like to communicate to it from my Android Studio made app. Specifically I would like to start a javascript with node.js on the RPI. So the RPI should be sort of an headless machine controlled with a smartphone.

However, I find it difficult to get an overview of all the options of how to create this communication, and I cannot find a good beginners guide of how to accomplish this.

Ideally it should work without access to internet. From what I can find I should make a local network connection, but I dont know how to do this. Can you help me?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can setup an access point on the RasPi so the smartphone can connect to it. There are hundreds of tutorials about this on the web, but many of them are outdated. The official Raspberry Pi web site for this you can find at [Setting up a Raspberry Pi as a routed wireless access point](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point-routed.md) or at [Setting up a Raspberry Pi as a bridged wireless access point](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point-bridged.md) but both of them show in addition to create an access point, how to connect the subnet to the internet. To have a stand alone access point you can use [Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point - the easy way](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88234/79866). Just follow section **♦ Setting up a stand alone access point**.

Comment: Thank you so much for guiding me in the right direction. It works.